# play framework 2.0 reverse routing

Tags: playframework-2.0

I'm a newbie at Java and I'm using the play framework 2.0 for a project and was wondering how to use the reverse routing functionality. We have the following:

In the routes file

```
GET /                controllers.Application.index()
GET /myapp/storage   controllers.myapp.AnotherController.index()
```

So to use reverse routing:

```
controllers.routes.ref.Application.index()
```

but what about `AnotherController`?

If I use `controllers.routes.ref.AnotherController.index()` in a test, the play framework will throw an error "cannot find symbol".

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just place your AnotherController.java within the app.controllers package as well?

Comment: I was hoping to group controllers into individual packages. When making the GET request with the defined route "GET /test  controllers.myapp.AnotherController.index()" the play framework resolved it without an issue. So I was hoping the reverse routing would also work with this setup.

Comment: And did you try `ontrollers.routes.ref.myapp.AnotherController.index()` ?

Comment: Yes I tried controllers.routes.ref.myapp.AnotherController.index() and  it reports cannot find symbol myapp. What avik suggested worked perfectly ... controllers.myapp.routes.AnotherController.index.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try dropping the `ref` element. I use the following structure for reverse routes in my play-2.0.4 app:

```
<full-package-name>.routes.<controller>.<action>
```

So the reverse route to your second action would thus be:

```
controllers.myapp.routes.AnotherController.index()
```

Given that your action takes no parameters, I guess you can also drop the brackets:

```
controllers.myapp.routes.AnotherController.index
```

Comment: Thanks avik.. Worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 1):

In this way worked for me. I don't know why:

```
activator clean
activator run
```